# Can't update header area in view

Tags: 7, views

When I'm updating the heasder area in my view and hit Apply (all displays), I get a page full of cryptic code like

```
[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"seven","theme_token":"nktojBAhwknIwX4rM0nJ0129z8flAy8_R7C7RpTZNUo","jquery_version":"1.8"},"ckeditor":{"input_formats":{"filtered_html":{"customConfig":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckeditor.config.js?","defaultLanguage":"en","toolbar":"[\n    [\u0027Source\u0027],\n    [\u0027Cut\u0027,\u0027Copy\u0027,\u0027Paste\u0027,\u0027PasteText\u0027,\u0027PasteFromWord\u0027,\u0027-\u0027,\u0027SpellChecker\u0027,\u0027Scayt\u0027],\n    [\u0027Undo\u0027,\u0027Redo\u0027,\u0027Find\u0027,\u0027Replace\u0027,\u0027-\u0027,\u0027SelectAll\u0027,\u0027RemoveFormat\u0027],\n    [\u0027Image\u0027,\u0027Flash\u0027,\u0027Table\u0027,\u0027HorizontalRule\u0027,\u0027Smiley\u0027,\u0027SpecialChar\u0027,\u0027Iframe\u0027],\n    \u0027\/\u0027,\n    [\u0027Bold\u0027,\u0027Italic\u0027,\u0027Underline\u0027,\u0027Strike\u0027,\u0027-\u0027,\u0027Subscript\u0027,\u0027Superscript\u0027],\n    [\u0027NumberedList\u0027,\u0027BulletedList\u0027,\u0027-\u0027,\u0027Outdent\u0027,\u0027Indent\u0027,\u0027Blockquote\u0027,\u0027CreateDiv\u0027],\n    [\u0027JustifyLeft\u0027,\u0027JustifyCenter\u0027,\u0027JustifyRight\u0027,\u0027JustifyBlock\u0027,\u0027-\u0027,\u0027BidiRtl\u0027,\u0027BidiLtr\u0027],\n    [\u0027Link\u0027,\u0027Unlink\u0027,\u0027Anchor\u0027,\u0027Linkit\u0027,\u0027LinkToNode\u0027,\u0027LinkToMenu\u0027],\n    \u0027\/\u0027,\n    [\u0027Format\u0027,\u0027Font\u0027,\u0027FontSize\u0027],\n    [\u0027TextColor\u0027,\u0027BGColor\u0027],\n    [\u0027Maximize\u0027,\u0027ShowBlocks\u0027],\n    [\u0027DrupalBreak\u0027,\u0027DrupalPageBreak\u0027]\n]","enterMode":1,"shiftEnterMode":2,"toolbarStartupExpanded":true,"width":"100%","skin":"moono","format_tags":"p;div;pre;address;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6","show_toggle":"t","default":"t","allowedContent":true,"ss":"2","loadPlugins":{"drupalbreaks":{"name":"drupalbreaks","desc":"Plugin for inserting Drupal teaser and page breaks.","path":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/plugins\/drupalbreaks\/","buttons":{"DrupalBreak":{"label":"DrupalBreak","icon":"images\/drupalbreak.png"}},"default":"t"},"imce":{"name":"imce","desc":"Plugin for inserting files from IMCE without image dialog","path":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/plugins\/imce\/","buttons":{"IMCE":{"label":"IMCE","icon":"images\/icon.png"}},"default":"f"}},"scayt_autoStartup":false,"filebrowserBrowseUrl":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckfinder\/ckfinder.html?id=Advanced","filebrowserImageBrowseUrl":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckfinder\/ckfinder.html?Type=Images\u0026id=Advanced","filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckfinder\/ckfinder.html?Type=Flash\u0026id=Advanced","filebrowserUploadUrl":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckfinder\/core\/connector\/php\/connector.php?command=QuickUpload\u0026type=Files\u0026id=Advanced","filebrowserImageUploadUrl":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckfinder\/core\/connector\/php\/connector.php?command=QuickUpload\u0026type=Images\u0026id=Advanced","filebrowserFlashUploadUrl":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckfinder\/core\/connector\/php\/connector.php?command=QuickUpload\u0026type=Flash\u0026id=Advanced","stylesCombo_stylesSet":"drupal:\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckeditor.styles.js","contentsCss":["\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/css\/ckeditor.css?oahnlb","\/sites\/all\/libraries\/ckeditor\/contents.css?oahnlb"]},"full_html":{"customConfig":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckeditor.config.js?","defaultLanguage":"en","toolbar":"[\n    [\u0027Source\u0027],\n    [\u0027Cut\u0027,\u0027Copy\u0027,\u0027Paste\u0027,\u0027PasteText\u0027,\u0027PasteFromWord\u0027,\u0027-\u0027,\u0027SpellChecker\u0027,\u0027Scayt\u0027],\n    [\u0027Undo\u0027,\u0027Redo\u0027,\u0027Find\u0027,\u0027Replace\u0027,\u0027-\u0027,\u0027SelectAll\u0027],\n    [\u0027Image\u0027,\u0027Flash\u0027,\u0027Table\u0027,\u0027HorizontalRule\u0027,\u0027Smiley\u0027,\u0027SpecialChar\u0027,\u0027Iframe\u0027],\n    \u0027\/\u0027,\n    [\u0027Bold\u0027,\u0027Italic\u0027,\u0027Underline\u0027,\u0027Strike\u0027,\u0027-\u0027,\u0027Subscript\u0027,\u0027Superscript\u0027,\u0027-\u0027,\u0027RemoveFormat\u0027],\n    [\u0027NumberedList\u0027,\u0027BulletedList\u0027,\u0027-\u0027,\u0027Outdent\u0027,\u0027Indent\u0027,\u0027Blockquote\u0027,\u0027CreateDiv\u0027],\n    [\u0027JustifyLeft\u0027,\u0027JustifyCenter\u0027,\u0027JustifyRight\u0027,\u0027JustifyBlock\u0027,\u0027-\u0027,\u0027BidiLtr\u0027,\u0027BidiRtl\u0027,\u0027-\u0027,\u0027Language\u0027],\n    [\u0027Link\u0027,\u0027Unlink\u0027,\u0027Anchor\u0027,\u0027Linkit\u0027,\u0027LinkToNode\u0027,\u0027LinkToMenu\u0027],\n    \u0027\/\u0027,\n    [\u0027Format\u0027,\u0027Font\u0027,\u0027FontSize\u0027],\n    [\u0027TextColor\u0027,\u0027BGColor\u0027],\n    [\u0027Maximize\u0027,\u0027ShowBlocks\u0027],\n    [\u0027DrupalBreak\u0027,\u0027DrupalPageBreak\u0027]\n]","enterMode":1,"shiftEnterMode":2,"toolbarStartupExpanded":true,"width":"100%","skin":"moono","format_tags":"p;div;pre;address;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6","show_toggle":"t","default":"t","allowedContent":true,"ss":"2","loadPlugins":{"drupalbreaks":{"name":"drupalbreaks","desc":"Plugin for inserting Drupal teaser and page breaks.","path":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/plugins\/drupalbreaks\/","buttons":{"DrupalBreak":{"label":"DrupalBreak","icon":"images\/drupalbreak.png"}},"default":"t"},"imce":{"name":"imce","desc":"Plugin for inserting files from IMCE without image dialog","path":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/plugins\/imce\/","buttons":{"IMCE":{"label":"IMCE","icon":"images\/icon.png"}},"default":"f"}},"scayt_autoStartup":false,"filebrowserBrowseUrl":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckfinder\/ckfinder.html?id=Full","filebrowserImageBrowseUrl":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckfinder\/ckfinder.html?Type=Images\u0026id=Full","filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckfinder\/ckfinder.html?Type=Flash\u0026id=Full","filebrowserUploadUrl":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckfinder\/core\/connector\/php\/connector.php?command=QuickUpload\u0026type=Files\u0026id=Full","filebrowserImageUploadUrl":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckfinder\/core\/connector\/php\/connector.php?command=QuickUpload\u0026type=Images\u0026id=Full","filebrowserFlashUploadUrl":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckfinder\/core\/connector\/php\/connector.php?command=QuickUpload\u0026type=Flash\u0026id=Full","stylesCombo_stylesSet":"drupal:\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/ckeditor.styles.js","contentsCss":["\/sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/css\/ckeditor.css?oahnlb","\/sites\/all\/libraries\/ckeditor\/contents.css?oahnlb"]}},"plugins":[]},"CTools":{"dependent":{"edit-options-token-help":{"values":{"edit-options-tokenize":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"}}},"urlIsAjaxTrusted":{"\/admin\/structure\/views\/ajax\/config-item\/golf_feed\/page\/header\/area":true}},"merge":true},{"command":"viewsDismissForm"},{"command":"viewsShowButtons","changed":true},{"command":"viewsTriggerPreview"},{"command":"insert","method":"html","selector":"#views-tab-page","data":"\u003Cdiv id=\u0022edit-display-settings-details\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv id=\u0022edit-display-settings-top\u0022 class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-actions views-ui-display-tab-bucket clearfix\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-no-js ctools-button ctools-dropbutton\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-link\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022#\u0022 class=\u0022ctools-twisty ctools-text\u0022\u003Eopen\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-content\u0022\u003E\u003Cul class=\u0022horizontal right actions\u0022\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022view\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022\/talking-rock-golf-course\u0022\u003Eview Page\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/li\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022duplicate\u0022\u003E\u003Cinput type=\u0022submit\u0022 name=\u0022op\u0022 value=\u0022clone Page\u0022 class=\u0022form-submit\u0022 \/\u003E\u003C\/li\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022delete\u0022\u003E\u003Cinput type=\u0022submit\u0022 name=\u0022op\u0022 value=\u0022delete Page\u0022 class=\u0022form-submit\u0022 \/\u003E\u003C\/li\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022disable\u0022\u003E\u003Cinput type=\u0022submit\u0022 name=\u0022op\u0022 value=\u0022disable Page\u0022 class=\u0022form-submit\u0022 \/\u003E\u003C\/li\u003E\u003C\/ul\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting odd clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EDisplay name:\u003C\/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/display\/golf_feed\/page\/display_title\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Page\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-display-title\u0022\u003EPage\u003C\/a\u003E  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv id=\u0022edit-display-settings-main\u0022 class=\u0022clearfix views-display-columns\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-column first\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket title\u0022 \u003E\n          \u003Ch3\u003ETitle\u003C\/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting defaulted even clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003ETitle:\u003C\/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/display\/golf_feed\/page\/title\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Change the title that this display will use.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-title\u0022\u003ETalking Rock Golf Course\u003C\/a\u003E  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket format\u0022 \u003E\n          \u003Ch3\u003EFormat\u003C\/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting defaulted odd clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EFormat:\u003C\/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/display\/golf_feed\/page\/style_plugin\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Change the way content is formatted.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-style-plugin\u0022\u003EUnformatted list\u003C\/a\u003E\u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003E\u0026nbsp;|\u0026nbsp;\u003C\/span\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/display\/golf_feed\/page\/style_options\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link views-button-configure\u0022 title=\u0022Change settings for this format\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-style-options\u0022\u003E\u003Cspan\u003ESettings\u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/a\u003E  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting defaulted even clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EShow:\u003C\/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/display\/golf_feed\/page\/row_plugin\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Change the way each row in the view is styled.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-row-plugin\u0022\u003EContent\u003C\/a\u003E\u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003E\u0026nbsp;|\u0026nbsp;\u003C\/span\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/display\/golf_feed\/page\/row_options\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link views-button-configure\u0022 title=\u0022Change settings for this style\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-row-options\u0022\u003E\u003Cspan\u003ETeaser\u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/a\u003E  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket fields\u0022 \u003E\n          \u003Ch3\u003EFields\u003C\/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting\u0022\u003EThe selected style or row format does not utilize fields.\u003C\/div\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket filter-criteria\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-no-js ctools-dropbutton ctools-button views-ui-settings-bucket-operations\u0022 id=\u0022ctools-button-1\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-link\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022#\u0022 class=\u0022ctools-twisty ctools-text\u0022\u003Eopen\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-content\u0022\u003E\u003Cul class=\u0022actions horizontal right\u0022\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022add first\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/add-item\/golf_feed\/page\/filter\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact add views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Add\u0022 id=\u0022views-add-filter\u0022\u003EAdd\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/li\u003E\n\u003Cli class=\u0022rearrange last\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/rearrange-filter\/golf_feed\/page\/filter\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact rearrange views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Rearrange\u0022 id=\u0022views-rearrange-filter\u0022\u003EAnd\/Or, Rearrange\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/li\u003E\n\u003C\/ul\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E        \u003Ch3\u003EFilter criteria\u003C\/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting page-filter-status odd clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/config-item\/golf_feed\/page\/filter\/status\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link\u0022\u003EContent: Published (Yes)\u003C\/a\u003E  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting page-filter-type even clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/config-item\/golf_feed\/page\/filter\/type\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link\u0022\u003EContent: Type (= Golf Content)\u003C\/a\u003E  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting page-filter-field-display-in-golf-news-feed-value odd clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/config-item\/golf_feed\/page\/filter\/field_display_in_golf_news_feed_value\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link\u0022\u003EContent: Display in Golf news feed (= On)\u003C\/a\u003E  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket sort-criteria\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-no-js ctools-dropbutton ctools-button views-ui-settings-bucket-operations\u0022 id=\u0022ctools-button-2\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-link\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022#\u0022 class=\u0022ctools-twisty ctools-text\u0022\u003Eopen\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-content\u0022\u003E\u003Cul class=\u0022actions horizontal right\u0022\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022add first\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/add-item\/golf_feed\/page\/sort\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact add views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Add\u0022 id=\u0022views-add-sort\u0022\u003EAdd\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/li\u003E\n\u003Cli class=\u0022rearrange last\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/rearrange\/golf_feed\/page\/sort\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact rearrange views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Rearrange\u0022 id=\u0022views-rearrange-sort\u0022\u003ERearrange\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/li\u003E\n\u003C\/ul\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E        \u003Ch3\u003ESort criteria\u003C\/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting page-sort-created even clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/config-item\/golf_feed\/page\/sort\/created\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link\u0022\u003EContent: Post date (desc)\u003C\/a\u003E  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-column second\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket page-settings\u0022 \u003E\n          \u003Ch3\u003EPage settings\u003C\/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting odd clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EPath:\u003C\/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/display\/golf_feed\/page\/path\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022\/talking-rock-golf-cours...\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-path\u0022\u003E\/talking-rock-golf-cours...\u003C\/a\u003E  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting even clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EMenu:\u003C\/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca ...
```

This even happens when I just add a strinf "test" to my existing header content.
While the change seems to be saved, it won't apply to the actual view as I never get the chance to actually save & apply my changes. Any idea what's happening here? I'm on `Views: 7.x-3.14` and `core 7.50`

**EDIT1**
And I already have the `Jquery Update` module installed.

Comment: Does this happen on all other views? or only on a specific one?

Comment: Did you override the core jQuery?

Comment: @NoSssweat only this one caused issues... another one I have seems to work fine.

Comment: @cerr create a new view, add the header part first, then re-create your buggy view setup, step by step, until it breaks.

Comment: @NoSssweat I actually don't know what broke or fixed it, it seemed to work fine today... It's a bit odd, I hadn't touched the site in a couple of days....

Comment: @cerr maybe you just needed to flush the cache or something, glad to hear the problem is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue to and the problem for me was with JQuery.  So take a look at what JQuery is being used.  In my case I installed the 'Jquery Update' module and sorted it with that.

Hope this helps you too.